# Does a Content-Type header on a GET request ever cary semantic meaning?

Tags: rest, content-type, http-get

So I've been embroiled in a discussion as to the appropriate interpretation of Content-Type headers in a GET request.  I plan on discarding the value of the Content-Type header on all GET requests to the service, as while it is permissible for a GET request to contain a body, server semantics for a GET request are restricted such that the body has no semantic meaning to the request.

So does the Content-Type of a GET request, which may or may not contain a message body, ever cary semantic meaning?

Can I safely discard it, or is there something I am overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

The `Content-Type` of a GET request isn't useful and typically is not sent.  As you state, if there is no content the type specified is irrelevant.

Conversely, the `Accept` header tells you what the client expects in return.

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 2616 Section 4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.3) states:

> The presence of a message-body in a request is signaled by the
> inclusion of a Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding header field in
> the request's message-headers. **A message-body MUST NOT be included in
> a request if the specification of the request method (section 5.1.1)
> does not allow sending an entity-body in requests. A server SHOULD
> read and forward a message-body on any request; if the request method
> does not include defined semantics for an entity-body, then the
> message-body SHOULD be ignored when handling the request.**

A `GET` request does not define any semantics for a message body, thus the message body, and its accompanied `Content-Type` if present, are to be ignored.